# How to solve error does not contain a definition for - new to C#

Tags: c#, .net-core

I started learning c# after programming in nodejs/typescript.

I came across the following error:

> TypeTests.cs(22,50): error CS1061: 'Book' does not contain a definition for 'name' and no accessible extension method 'name' accepting a first argument of type 'Book' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

The is my class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace GradeBook
{
    public class Book
    {
        // this is how we generate a constructor in c#
        public Book(string name)
        {
            grades = new List<double>();
            Name = name;
        }

        public void AddGrade(double grade)
        {
            grades.Add(grade);
            Console.WriteLine($"A new added grade: {grade:N2}");
        }

        public Stats GetStats()
        {
            var result = new Stats();
            result.Average = 0.0;
            result.High = double.MinValue;
            result.Low = double.MaxValue;

            foreach (var grade in grades)
            {
                // log hightest grades
                result.High = Math.Max(grade, result.High);
                // log lowest grades
                result.Low = Math.Min(grade, result.Low);
                result.Average += grade;
            }

            result.Average /= grades.Count;

            return result;
        }

        // its no longer a variable it is now called field in c#
        private List<double> grades;
        public string Name;
    }
}
```

My test class:

```
using System;
using Xunit;

namespace GradeBook.tests
{
    /*
    // Guideline to writing good unit tests:
    // arrange the test
    // act - the actual actions
    // assert - the values that are computed in the act section
   */
    public class TypeTests
    {
        [Fact]
        public void CSharpIsPassByValue()
        {
            // arrange
            var book1 = GetBook("My Book");
            GetBookSetName(book1, "New Book Name!");
            //assert
            Assert.Equal("My Book", book1.name);
        }

        private void GetBookSetName(Book book, string name)
        {
            book = new Book(name);
        }

        [Fact]
        public void CanSetNameFromReference()
        {
            // arrange
            var book1 = GetBook("My Book");
            SetName(book1, "New Book Name!");
            //assert
            Assert.Equal("New Book Name!", book1.name);
        }

        private void SetName(Book book, string name)
        {
            book.Name = name;
        }

        [Fact]
        public void GetBookReturnsDifferentObjects()
        {
            // arrange
            var book1 = GetBook("My Book");
            var book2 = GetBook("My Other Book");

            //assert
            Assert.Equal("My Book", book1.name);
            Assert.Equal("My Other Book", book2.name);
            Assert.NotSame(book1, book2);
        }

        [Fact]
        public void TwoVarsCanReferenceSameObject()
        {
            var book1 = GetBook("Book 1");
            var book2 = book1;

            Assert.Same(book1, book2);
            Assert.True(Object.ReferenceEquals(book1, book2));
        }

        Book GetBook(string name)
        {
            return new Book(name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line of your code throws that exception?

Answer (score 6):

Field names are case sensitive in C#, so in this line:

```
Assert.Equal("My Book", book1.name);
```

`name` should be `Name`:

```
Assert.Equal("My Book", book1.Name);
```

There are actually a few places in your code that this will need correcting.